# CSS 100% height problem

Tags: css

I'm working on a new template and I'm having a 100% height issue, tried various style combinations but cant get it to work. [Here is the link](http://www.tositesas.com/dolopia/template.php), the light beige area should extend below the end of the left content but it doesn't. What's messing my layout up? It's probably a clearing issue but how & where? Thanks.

Comment: Well, your code is poorly written. At first remove `link` duplicates. They are allowed only in `head` tag. Second, don't use `height:100%`. The structure should be rewritten. Either use background-image for the content wrapper to visualize the graphical borders or if it's too hard for you just use table-based layout.

Comment: Apart from the multiple linking (which was done deliberately until I finish all the styling, removed now to be easier for you to debug) Which areas do you mean when you say the code is poorly written?

Comment: @bikey11 - No offense, really. I refer to a few things: the way you try to print left and right graphical border, `#page{display:inline}`, `#wrapper-left` width in px but `#page` in %, unnecessary `<div class="clear"></div>` (without any CSS), no wrapping the whole header to simplify positioning elements below it.

Comment: No offense taken, I'm trying to learn and correcting my mistakes! :)
I'll look into the parts you pointed out and I'll see about improving them. Thanks!

Comment: As for the borders, i know it's akward (i've never had to do it in other designs) but because of the way I wanted the lines to appear, I couldn't think of another way. The traditional repeat-x wouldn't work for me because the lines dont have a pattern. Maybe I havent sliced my images correctly, I really can't think of another way though.

Answer (score 0):

that's because 100% is relative to the viewport, you want it to be relative to the document.
you need to add an element and clear:both, after the page's div, and remove the height:100%

Comment: What element (on my page) should I remove the height: 100% from? I've declared it in several places. Also, if I put an empty div at the end of the template with display:block; clear:both; will that work?

Answer (score 0):

OK first off, you have four declarations for the stylesheets, they only need to appear once in the head section of your page.

What I suggest you do as an overall approach on div layouts is sketch out the containers you want with a 1 pixel coloured border, then, using firebug and firefox you can adjust the design to how you want dynamically and see how it behaves.

Once you have that down, refine it and add your images.

Comment: yes, i know, it's only because I'm declaring the stylesheets in all files that consist the template, once I'me done with the styling I'll have them removed.